# `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I am new to postgresql. I am trying to use postgresql with ruby on rails. I have just installed postgresql and I have just created my database. But when I try to run postgresql on localhost on port 5432 I get the above error.

Comment: if you want u can allow localhost connections without a password by putting `trust` instead of `peer`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I figured out the solution:

I changed my settings in `pg_hba.conf` to

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

where initially instead of `trust` it was `md5`.
Then just doing `service postgresql restrart` did the trick!!